# How to measure writes on hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I would like to measure how much data is written in one session (from log-in till the log-out) on my hard drive.

How I can do this? I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Try running the performance monitor if you are using Windows. It also gives you pretty graphs and charts!

Comment: @Peter can you tell me how to use this tool?

Comment: Search in Windows or Run > perfmon amd click on the Performance Monitor. Add counters and select something like Storage Spaces Tier and use Tier Write bytes/second